# Как проверить на пустоту значение date из Mysql?

Tags: дата, php, mysql

По умолчанию для типа `date` в поле Mysql устанавливается значение `0000-00-00`.
Как проверить, что установлено это значение? Грубо говоря, на "пустоту".

Comment: Так и проверить, на равенство данной строке.

Кстати, обычный if для данной строки вернет false, т.к. преобразование к int даст 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($date == 0000-00-00) { } else { }
```

**Обновление**

К примеру, $date = 2014-00-00

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
if ($month == 00 && $day == 00) { 
    echo $year; // выведет 2014 
}
```

Comment: Тогда косвенный вопрос, если пользователь указал только год, а остальное по 00, как обработать лучше, чтобы нули не отобразить?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Может указать для поля `date` по умолчанию значение `NULL`, чтобы проверять на `empty()?`

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk В каком виде будет храниться заполненная юзером строка?

Comment: В формате `date`.